# Integration of Image-To-Text issue with react-native and @react-native-ml-kit/text-recognition

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, ocr

I have a react native project and within this project. I want to integrate the abillity for the user to take a photo or select a photo from their library. Once the image is selected, I want to then extract all of the text from the image and have it show up as text. I am getting errors and I have tried 4 different npm packages just to get this simple concept to work and no matter what I try, It will not work for some reason. Right now the package I am testing is `@react-native-ml-kit/text-recognition`. I have it installed and imported. When I try to process the image, I keep getting the following error:

```
 ERROR  Error: The package '@react-native-ml-kit/text-recognition' doesn't seem to be linked. Make sure: 

- You have run 'pod install'
- You rebuilt the app after installing the package
- You are not using Expo managed workflow
, js engine: hermes
```

I went through and ran 10 commands and tried so many different things to fix the error because the package is not linked to react-native. I tried:

`react-native link @react-native-ml-kit/text-recognition` and it did not work. I tried `npx pod install` and that did not work. I reset the cache and reset the simulator but nothing fixed this issue.

Here is my code (the issues is coming from the `performOCR` function right above the jsx):

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Image, Text, TouchableOpacity, View} from 'react-native';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
import * as ImageManipulator from 'expo-image-manipulator';
import TextRecognition from '@react-native-ml-kit/text-recognition';

const NewTransactionScreen = () => {
  const [ocrResult, setOcrResult] = useState('');
  const [galleryPermission, setGalleryPermission] = useState(
    ImagePicker.useMediaLibraryPermissions(),
  );
  const [cameraPermission, setCameraPermission] = useState(
    ImagePicker.useCameraPermissions(),
  );
  const [preprocessedImage, setPreprocessedImage] = useState('');

  ...

  const performOCR = () => {
    TextRecognition.recognize(preprocessedImage)
      .then(results => {
        console.log('Recognized text:', results.text);

        for (let block of results.blocks) {
          console.log('Block text:', block.text);
          console.log('Block frame:', block.frame);

          for (let line of block.lines) {
            console.log('Line text:', line.text);
            console.log('Line frame:', line.frame);
          }
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Add new transaction: options below</Text>
      {cameraPermission ? (
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            processCameraImage();
          }}>
          <Text>Camera</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ) : (
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            grantCameraAccess();
          }}>
          <Text>Grant Camera Access</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )}
      {galleryPermission ? (
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            processLibraryImage();
          }}>
          <Text>Photo Library</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ) : (
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            grantLibraryAccess();
          }}>
          <Text>Grant Camera Access</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )}
      {preprocessedImage ? (
        <Image
          style={{width: 320, height: 400, margin: 10}}
          source={{uri: preprocessedImage}}
        />
      ) : null}
      {preprocessedImage ? (
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            performOCR();
          }}>
          <Text>Scan Receipt</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ) : null}
    </View>
  );
};

export default NewTransactionScreen;
```

You can only call the `performOCR` fucntion if there is a URI in `preprocessedImage`.

Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.19.3",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-community/viewpager": "^5.0.11",
    "@react-native-ml-kit/text-recognition": "^1.5.1",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.11",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.19",
    "expo": "^49.0.16",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "11.3.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "^14.5.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "^1.7.1",
    "firebase": "^10.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.13.3",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^7.0.2",
    "react-native-image-resizer": "^1.4.5",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.5.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.7.3",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.26.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "^0.72.2",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.72.11",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.24",
    "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.16",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.76.8",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.8.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16"
  }
}
```

Here is my podfile:

````
# Resolve react_native_pods.rb with node to allow for hoisting
require Pod::Executable.execute_command('node', ['-p',
  'require.resolve(
    "react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb",
    {paths: [process.argv[1]]},
  )', __dir__]).strip

platform :ios, min_ios_version_supported
prepare_react_native_project!

# If you are using a `react-native-flipper` your iOS build will fail when `NO_FLIPPER=1` is set.
# because `react-native-flipper` depends on (FlipperKit,...) that will be excluded
#
# To fix this you can also exclude `react-native-flipper` using a `react-native.config.js`
# ```js
# module.exports = {
#   dependencies: {
#     ...(process.env.NO_FLIPPER ? { 'react-native-flipper': { platforms: { ios: null } } } : {}),
# ```
flipper_config = ENV['NO_FLIPPER'] == "1" ? FlipperConfiguration.disabled : FlipperConfiguration.enabled

linkage = ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']
if linkage != nil
  Pod::UI.puts "Configuring Pod with #{linkage}ally linked Frameworks".green
  use_frameworks! :linkage => linkage.to_sym
end

target 'Mobile' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # Hermes is now enabled by default. Disable by setting this flag to false.
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # Enables Flipper.
    #
    # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
    # you should disable the next line.
    :flipper_configuration => flipper_config,
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  target 'MobileTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    # https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/packages/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb#L197-L202
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      config[:reactNativePath],
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
    )
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end
end
````

Answer (score 0):

Try using image to text api in apilayer.com. Example below:

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar"; 
import { useState } from "react"; 
import { 
    Button, 
    StyleSheet, 
    Text, 
    Image, 
    SafeAreaView, 
} from "react-native"; 
import * as ImagePicker from "expo-image-picker"; 

export default function App() { 

    // State to hold the selected image 
    const [image, setImage] = useState(null); 
    
    // State to hold extracted text 
    const [extractedText, setExtractedText] = 
        useState(""); 

    // Function to pick an image from the 
    // device's gallery 
    const pickImageGallery = async () => { 
        let result = 
            await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({ 
                mediaTypes: 
                    ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images, 
                allowsEditing: true, 
                base64: true, 
                allowsMultipleSelection: false, 
            }); 
        if (!result.canceled) { 
        
            // Perform OCR on the selected image 
            performOCR(result.assets[0]); 
            
            // Set the selected image in state 
            setImage(result.assets[0].uri); 
        } 
    }; 

    // Function to capture an image using the 
    // device's camera 
    const pickImageCamera = async () => { 
        let result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({ 
            mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images, 
            allowsEditing: true, 
            base64: true, 
            allowsMultipleSelection: false, 
        }); 
        if (!result.canceled) { 
        
            // Perform OCR on the captured image 
            // Set the captured image in state 
            performOCR(result.assets[0]); 
            setImage(result.assets[0].uri); 
        } 
    }; 

    // Function to perform OCR on an image 
    // and extract text 
    const performOCR = (file) => { 
        let myHeaders = new Headers(); 
        myHeaders.append( 
            "apikey", 
            
            // ADDD YOUR API KEY HERE 
            "FEmvQr5uj99ZUvk3essuYb6P5lLLBS20"
        ); 
        myHeaders.append( 
            "Content-Type", 
            "multipart/form-data"
        ); 

        let raw = file; 
        let requestOptions = { 
            method: "POST", 
            redirect: "follow", 
            headers: myHeaders, 
            body: raw, 
        }; 

        // Send a POST request to the OCR API 
        fetch( 
            "https://api.apilayer.com/image_to_text/upload", 
            requestOptions 
        ) 
            .then((response) => response.json()) 
            .then((result) => { 
            
                // Set the extracted text in state 
                setExtractedText(result["all_text"]); 
            }) 
            .catch((error) => console.log("error", error)); 
    }; 

    return ( 
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}> 
            <Text style={styles.heading}> 
                Welcome to GeeksforGeeks 
            </Text> 
            <Text style={styles.heading2}> 
                Image to Text App 
            </Text> 
            <Button 
                title="Pick an image from gallery"
                onPress={pickImageGallery} 
            /> 
            <Button 
                title="Pick an image from camera"
                onPress={pickImageCamera} 
            /> 
            {image && ( 
                <Image 
                    source={{ uri: image }} 
                    style={{ 
                        width: 400, 
                        height: 300, 
                        objectFit: "contain", 
                    }} 
                /> 
            )} 

            <Text style={styles.text1}> 
                Extracted text: 
            </Text> 
            <Text style={styles.text1}> 
                {extractedText} 
            </Text> 
            <StatusBar style="auto" /> 
        </SafeAreaView> 
    ); 
} 

const styles = StyleSheet.create({ 
    container: { 
        display: "flex", 
        alignContent: "center", 
        alignItems: "center", 
        justifyContent: "space-evenly", 
        backgroundColor: "#fff", 
        height: "100%", 
    }, 
    heading: { 
        fontSize: 28, 
        fontWeight: "bold", 
        marginBottom: 10, 
        color: "green", 
        textAlign: "center", 
    }, 
    heading2: { 
        fontSize: 22, 
        fontWeight: "bold", 
        marginBottom: 10, 
        color: "black", 
        textAlign: "center", 
    }, 
    text1: { 
        fontSize: 16, 
        marginBottom: 10, 
        color: "black", 
        fontWeight: "bold", 
    }, 
});
```